# Is there a way to specify the folds (using my data) with H2O AutoML?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, h2o, automl, h2o.ai

I'm trying to specify the folds for cross-validation in H20. I want to select the subset from the data to be a specific fold. For example, fold number 1 corresponds to my subject 1 data. The fold number 2 to my subject 2 and so on. Is there a way to do it?

I checked the docs for H20 but I didn't find a way for specifying the fold based on my data.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's a way to do this in H2O AutoML and all the supervised H2O algorithms.

There's an argument called `fold_column` in which you specify the name of the column that defines the fold ID.  So if you have a `"subject_id"` column, just set `fold_column = "subject_id"`.

More info in the [docs](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/fold_column.html).